# Can we make .exe file from .py file for window 7/7 ultimate / 8 / 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, desktop-application, cx-freeze

I am working on a desktop application that I made by using the python language and some open-source library. When I convert that .py file to a .exe file using Pyinstaller it runs on window 10 but shows an error on window 7.  Is there any way to make one .exe for all window versions 7/8/10?

- List item

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the executable runs on 7, 8 and 10 you have to create the executable on the oldest OS, that should be supported.

In your case:

Run pyinstaller on a windows 7 machine

Answer (score 0):

For the .exe file to work on windows 7, you must make the exe file in windows 7. Make the exe in windows 7 and it will work in windows 8,8.1 and 10 also.